# Failed to run `rustc` error. (Rust cargo build issue)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Im trying to cargo build a file but have some issues.

I set rustup nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc default but still get the error.

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Error:

```
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

  Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names '-C link-arg=-s' --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit code: 1)
--- stderr
error: multiple input filenames provided (first two filenames are `-` and `'-C`)
```

Thanks for help and solutions

Comment: I don't think this is your problem (yet), but did you `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`?

Comment: I added the target and ran again cargo build but still get the exact 

error: multiple input filenames provided (first two filenames are `-` and `'-C'`)

Comment: I'd try specifying rustflags in .cargo/config.toml instead of command line.

Comment: Im using Windows so you mean cargo.toml right ?
What do i need to change ?
Im trying to get a .wasm file.

Comment: What shell do you use? I'm not sure that this way to specify environment variables is correct, since the quotes should not be preserved in the `rustc` invocation, if they are just delimiters.

Comment: @SurpriseMF no i mean `$projectfolder/.cargo/config.toml` https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Comment: Im using admin cmd. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have in my projectfolder just a Cargo.toml file and in my user folder a .cargo folder with bin folder, registry folder and .package-cache file.

Comment: On Repl.it im getting the error: error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `cmd`, try using [the `set` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) to set the environment variable. You can also try using double-quotes (`"`) or no quotes.

Comment: I created a new Rust folder: "create new ...(folder) --lib"
Then i tried: "RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown" and get still the error with multiple filenames.
Also set Rustflags ... and the cargo build didnt worked.

Comment: @SurpriseMF Did you read my answer? Try `RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-s" cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`. Also, just to make sure, are you using the old `cmd` or the new PowerShell?